# How to send parameter with try catch exception in yii2?

Tags: yii2

I have problem in sending email, looks like our server connection to mail server is unstable, sometimes it successfully sent, but sometimes it's not, it say ssl time out.

So my idea is catch timed out exception and insert in database then I can send later.

But I need to send few parameter with catch exception so I can insert database correctly.

So far what I want is something like this

```
try{
  $message = Yii::$app->mail->compose();
  if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
    $message->setFrom('from@domain.com');
  } else {
    $message->setFrom(Yii::$app->user->identity->email);
  }
  $message->setTo(Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'])
  ->setFrom(Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'])
  ->setTo("mymail@gmail.com")
  ->setSubject('Title 1')
  ->setHtmlBody("Hi, this is my content to check if registration email successfully sent")
  ->send();
  $mail_from = "no-reply@myweb.com";
  $mail_to = "customer@someweb.com";
  $content = "here is content of email"
  $other = "this other variable";
  return 1;

}catch(\Swift_TransportException $e, $mail_from, $mail_to, $content, $other){

  //if connection time out or something
  $queue = new Queue;
  $queue->mail_from = $mail_from;
  $queue->mail_to = $mail_to;
  $queue->content = $content;
  $queue->other = $other;
  $queue->fail_reason = $e->getMessage();
  $queue->save()
}
```

but it give me `undefined variable $mail_from, $mail_to, and etc`

How I can fix my problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the `undefined variable $mail_from, $mail_to, and etc` error it's better to declare the variables outside the `try` block. Because you're declaring the variables at the end of the `try`, it fails before these variables are ever initialised.

```
$mail_from = "no-reply@myweb.com";
$mail_to   = "customer@someweb.com";
$content   = "here is content of email"
$other     = "this other variable";

try {
    $message = Yii::$app->mail->compose();

    if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        $message->setFrom('from@domain.com');
    } else {
        $message->setFrom(Yii::$app->user->identity->email);
    }
    $message->setTo(Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'])
        ->setFrom(Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'])
        ->setTo("mymail@gmail.com")
        ->setSubject('Title 1')
        ->setHtmlBody("Hi, this is my content to check if registration email successfully sent")
        ->send();

    return 1;
} catch(\Swift_TransportException $e) {
    //if connection time out or something
    $queue = new Queue;
    $queue->mail_from = $mail_from;
        $queue->mail_to = $mail_to;
    $queue->content = $content;
    $queue->other = $other;
    $queue->fail_reason = $e->getMessage();
    $queue->save()
}
```

But there are more problems with this code. You're setting the `from` and `to` part multiple times. In the `if/else` you're calling `setFrom` and then again a few lines later. The same goes for `setTo`. The last call to the function will overrule the previous set value. So make sure you only call these functions once.